# undefined is not an object (data)

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I'm trying to implement `socket.io-client` in react-native, but it gives me an error.

**`Undefined is not an object (data)`**

```
sock = () => {
    const socket = openSocket(baseUrl);
    socket.on('newOrder', orders => {
      orders.length > 0
        ? this.setState(prevState => ({data: [...prevState.data, orders]}))
        : this.setState({
            data: [],
          });
    });
  };
```